# How often are miracles and supernatural experiences reported in Islam?

Tags: miracles

How common is it to hear about reports of supernatural events or miracles in Islam? How common is it that Muslims share testimonies of first-hand supernatural experiences? What kinds of extraordinary experiences are most frequently reported?

Notice that I'm not asking whether these reports are true or not. I'm just asking about their frequency and the types of experiences that are reported most often.

Answer (score 0):

Well this depends on whether they were actually supernatural events or just a trick played by some "Baba" calling himself a religious guru.
Muslims belief in miracles that were testified by Quran and Hadith. The biggest miracle is the Quran itself that's unchanged, unedited since revealed and compiled. Besides this miracles by The Prophet Muhammad (S.A.W) and his companions were the ones that are 100% believed to be true as they're backed by evidence and witnesses and recorded in books called "Sahih".

Now talking about the frequency, you'll find Muslims in Africa and Asia especially Subcontinent (India, Pakistan, Bangladesh) reporting such supernatural events very often.

Comment: Thanks Shehriar for the answer. However, I think the answer could be improved by adding explicit links to sources to back up the assertions made. For instance, can you reference some examples of Muslims in Africa or Asia reporting supernatural events?

Answer (score 0):

They depend on how superstitious individuals are.
In general, Islam is against miracles that happen after Muhammad's era.
However that does not stop many Muslims from believing in supernatural and metaphysical events on a daily basis like any other religious community.
They are not alone in this, and It is wrong to think of them as a special kind of people or special kind of belief.
Answering your question, it depends on the geographical region and the civilization level and it has nothing to do at all with the religion per se.

To make it clearer in an example,
People in Egypt, Iran or any country , do report the same frequency of miracles (and they compete between themselves) regardless to the religion (Christians, Muslims,  or any minority)

No difference in frequency, the difference is merely in how it looks like, what Miracle, what shape, what type, these type of things might be influenced by the religion, but not the fact that it is a miracle.

Another thing to note, that these Abrahimi religions are all the same (Judaism, Christianity and Islam) They are the same one religion in different shapes... Studying the linkage between them is very important.

Comment: When I asked the question, I was wondering if Islam had some sort of equivalent to the pentecostal / charismatic movement in Christianity, with their "revivals" and "miracle crusades" and stuff.

Comment: There are miracles, not exactly equivalent but they do have so many miracles of all kinds yes.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a few examples?

Comment: The types of miracle will vary, as I mentioned but talking about charismatic movement: Look at all the mircacles attributed to Ali Bin Abi Talib, and all his offspring mainly Husain.

Answer (score 0):

The types of miracle will vary, as I mentioned but talking about charismatic movement: Look at all the miracles attributed to Ali Bin Abi Talib, and all his offspring mainly Husain. Then there are so many defaulted sectors, The recent ones are all the miracles attributed to [Suliman Murshid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salman_al-Murshid),  There are also many local superstitious believes like "Abu Taqa", and all other shrines each with special set of miracles.  There are so many all depends on how intellectually retarded the  society is. I believe you are not concerned about the old Islamic myths  and miracles, they are also so many. I am not specialist in these but all I can tell you is that there are as many and as frequent  miracles for all metaphysical kind of belief. Islam/Christianity and Judaism are the same.

There are a couple of books about Sulieman, and I found this about Abu Taqa [online](http://%20%22Abu%20Taqa%22%20%5Ba%20shrine%20that%20belongs%20to%20one%20of%20the%20Righteous%20Guardians%20and%20which%20many%20Alawites%20claim%20possesses%20the%20miraculous%20ability%20to%20detect%20lies%5D):

> "Abu Taqa" [a shrine that belongs to one of the Righteous Guardians
> and which many Alawites claim possesses the miraculous ability to
> detect lies]

**There are so many such things all over the region.. (Again, I insist, All religions equally in that region)**

To make your search easier, simply search the internet for keywords such as (Karamat, Miracles, Shrine) you will find so many but the local believes are 1000 times more than what is publicly documented online. The usage of internet is not there yet.

Comment: Thanks for attempting to provide more specific examples, although I would appreciate it if you could include links to primary sources so I can read up on these cases more thoroughly. I am not sure how the rules are in Islam.SE, but generally most stackexchange sites expect you to cite reputable sources to support what is said in the answer.

Comment: I agree with you. I am from that region, I grew up with these traditional believes. Not all of them can be documented in reputable sources, but I will update my reply.